# i have a formula, trying to put it into python and this is what i have so far, whats the issue with it?

Tags: python

firstly, i want to make a program for this formula:
    "Capacity of all nodes X 4 X node_type X node_feature X 1.aspect_count

this is what i have so far:

```
    import math
node_type = 1
node_feature = 1
aspect_count = 0
capacity = 0
def capacity():
    capcaity = int(input("input the capacity of your node: "))

def aspect_count():
    aspect_count = int(input("input the number of aspects that their are: ")) / 10 + 1

def node_type():
    node_type = raw_input("input the type of node you have e.g. pale/bright/normal: ")

def node_feature():
    node_feature = raw_input("input the feature of your node e.g. hungry/pure/normal:")


def which_node_type():
    if node_type == pale:
        node_type = 1.1
    elif node_type == bright:
        node_type = 1.5
    else:
        node_type = 1.3

def which_node_feature():
    if node_feature == hungry:
        node_feature = 5
    elif node_feature == sinister:
        node_feature = 3
    elif node_feature == pure:
        node_feature = 4
    else:
        node_feature = 2.5

def price():
    price = capacity * 4 * which_node_type * which_node_feature * aspect_count
```

well, that is what i have so far but it throws issues about `elif` being a syntax error, i just wondered if anyone could help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Now i have changed the elif lines, i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 40, in 
  File "", line 38, in price
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'

any help on the above?

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the `elif`s - `elif node_feature == sinister:` should be a single line with a colon at the end.

Comment: You have turned this question into two questions.  Now, there are two answers answering different questions which is super confusing.  Please only ask one question per question.  You question about the `TypeError` should have been a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also note that you are not actually calling the functions in `price()` - should be

```
def price():
    price = capacity() * 4 * which_node_type() * which_node_feature() * aspect_count()
```

and your functions are not returning values; you need to `return` like so:

```
def capacity():
    return int(input("input the capacity of your node: "))
```

Finally, your code is kind of unstructured; I would rewrite it as a class, like so:

```
# assumes Python 2.x
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_one_of(prompt, values):
    while True:
        result = raw_input(prompt).strip()
        if result in values:
            return result
        else:
            print("  (must enter one of [{}])".format(", ".join(values)))

class Node(object):
    node_type_values = {"pale": 1.1, "normal": 1.3, "bright": 1.5}
    node_types = sorted(node_type_values.keys())

    node_feature_values = {"normal": 2.5, "sinister": 3, "pure": 4, "hungry": 5}
    node_features = sorted(node_feature_values.keys())

    @classmethod
    def from_prompt(cls):
        capacity     = get_int("Enter the node's capacity: ")
        node_type    = get_one_of("Enter the node's type: ", cls.node_types)
        node_feature = get_one_of("Enter the node's feature: ", cls.node_features)
        num_aspects  = get_int("Enter the node's aspect count: ")
        return cls(capacity, node_type, node_feature, num_aspects)

    def __init__(self, capacity, node_type, node_feature, num_aspects):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.node_type = node_type
        self.node_feature = node_feature
        self.num_aspects = num_aspects

    def price(self):
        return 4 * self.capacity * Node.node_type_values[self.node_type] * Node.node_feature_values[self.node_feature] * (1. + 0.1 * self.num_aspects)

def main():
    n = Node.from_prompt()
    print("Price is ${:0.2f}.".format(n.price()))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are writing your `elif` statements incorrectly.  Everything like this:

```
elif:
    node_feature == sinister:
```

needs to be written like this:

```
elif node_feature == sinister:
```

In other words, the condition to evaluate goes just after the `elif` keyword.